# JavaScript Alert in ActionScript

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

We can easily alert anything in java script. Is it possible to get this or similar alert in ActionScript ?

I have below test Class in Action Script. Trace does same as console.log() in java script. Is it possible to display messages in action script ?

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip; 
    public class ooas3 extends MovieClip{
        public var color:String = "red";
        public var num:Number = 100;
        public function ooas3() {
            theMovie_DoFSCommand(color,"ooas3 num is "+num);
        }


        function theMovie_DoFSCommand(color, args) {
                if (command == "red") {
                 trace(command + " - " + args);
        // Can above line is replaced by Alert similar to java Script Alert ?        
                }
        }       
    }   
}
```

As per the philipp's adivice I tested the below class on [actionscript docs:](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)

```
package {
       import flash.text.TextField;
       import flash.display.MovieClip;
       import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

       public class extint_test extends MovieClip {
         public function extint_test() {
           var isAvailable:Boolean = ExternalInterface.available;
           var availTxt:TextField = new TextField();
           availTxt.text = isAvailable.toString();
           addChild(availTxt);
         }
       }
     }
```

Above code alerts the "test" similar to javascript. This is a Flash Window that shows the message. But How to integrate similar code in my Class. i.e. How to do repalce `trace ("something")` with this Flash Alert window ?

Comment: yes see this : http://code.google.com/p/flash-console/  |-| http://labs.findsubstance.com/2008/02/26/firebugs-console-log-flash-debugging-made-easy/ http://code.google.com/p/flash-tracer/ |-| https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/flashtracer/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alerts can be done in Flash environment in 2 ways : 
 **1.** The best way is to use [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html). It calls up the javascript alert function and displays content accordingly. For example,

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

ExternalInterface.call("alert", "Hello ExternalInterface");
```

The swf when loaded in html shall invoke the alert window.

**2.** The second way is to write your own customized flash component/class which displays some movieclip with textfield . You need to write the functions to handle its visibility on button click("OK") 
 Something like alert.show is not possible in flash cs3 and above as the component **mx.controls.Alert** is available only in flash mx2004 and flex environment.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the ExternalInterface.call() method... look [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)

f.e.:

```
ExternalInterface.call( "alert", "hallo" );
```

Answer (score 1):

yes see this :

http://code.google.com/p/flash-console

http://labs.findsubstance.com/2008/02/26/firebugs-console-log-flash-debugging-made-easy/

http://code.google.com/p/flash-tracer

http://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/flashtracer

Answer (score 0):

try adding the following line of code.
`alert.show("alerts")` method

Comment: may be u have to give import stmts..  " import mx.controls.Alert;"

Comment: "mx.controls:Alert is not found" new Alert after importing the code also

Comment: Alert is a Flex class, not a Flash class